# can I rebuild an electron from a resources folder

Tags: javascript, build, electron

I have delete my electron .exe file and I figure out if it's possible to rebuild one from the resources files

this is my main folder
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8RU.jpg

and the resources folder
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEGQe.jpg

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, possibly.
Long answer, you would set it to the Current Working Directory and make sure the user has NodeJS installed then yes, you could recompile it from the resources folder.

Comment: Hey Jacob can you give me more information, how to do that

Comment: @user3224813 Go to (root)/resources/app.asar and use a system to extract the asar to get the source code (http://www.tc4shell.com/en/7zip/asar/) and you will want to create a recompile process then BAM ya done, if u need any more help then MSG me at https://www.reddit.com/user/MasterGamer9910